# VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME undefined, in Vulkan code

Tags: c++, graphics, vulkan

I'm attempting to write a simple vulkan based application, but when trying to add the surface extension to the list of enabled extensions, like so:

```
    enabledExtensions.push_back( VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME );
#if defined (_WIN32)
    enabledExtensions.push_back( VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME );
#else
    enabledExtensions.push_back( VK_KHR_XCB_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME );
#endif
```

Visual studio complains that `VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME`is undefined.

When I right click it and go to definition, it opens vulkan.h. Upon inspection of `VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR` I find this to be also undefined, which prevents the definition of `VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME`. Could someone explain how to fix this?

Answer (score 13):

As it turns out, I was missing some preprocessor directives in the project settings:

```
VK_PROTOTYPES
VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR
```

I hope this info helps out anyone who has the same problem.

Comment: There is no VK_PROTOTYPES, but VK_NO_PROTOTYPES, with opposite effect. In another words, to solve this issue you only need VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR

Comment: In my case, in order to simply expose `VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME`, all I needed was to add the `VK_USE_PLATFORM_WIN32_KHR` preprocessor define.
Great answer, great followup!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a common problem, currently you can fix this by adding the specific header

```
#if defined (_WIN32)
    #include <vulkan/vulkan_win32.h>
#elif defined(__linux__)
    #include <vulkan/vulkan_xcb.h>
#elif defined(__ANDROID__)
    #include <vulkan/vulkan_android.h>
#endif
```